# How can I get specific values from JObject in c#

Tags: c#, jobjectformatter

I need to retrieve specific values from API response. My response looks like one below. How can I access to [productCodeScheme] value of each pack?

```
dynamic api = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

// api contains
{
    "operationCode": "12200000",
    "packs": [
        {
            "pack": {
                "productCodeScheme": "ppn",
                "productCode": "15000436574634",
                "serialNumber": "0000000001",
                "batchId": "00001",
                "expiryDate": "201201"
            },
            "result": {
                "operationCode": "61020008",
                "warning": "The product code is invalid."
            }
        },
        {
            "pack": {
                "productCodeScheme": "gs1",
                "productCode": "15000436574634",
                "serialNumber": "0000000002",
                "batchId": "00001",
                "expiryDate": "201201"
            },
            "result": {
                "operationCode": "11310300",
                "information": "The pack has been marked as stolen.",
                "state": "Stolen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: go to website json2csharp - past your json there - it will give you classes; Use Newtonsoft json deserializer to deserialize json to these generated classes. Then you should find it much easier? Otherwise read docs? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: `string productCodeScheme = api.SelectToken(@"packs[0].pack.productCodeScheme ").Value<string>()` maybe like this?

Comment: Hello, please read section [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We expect here questions with specific problems. Your current question sounds more like a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your object to stay dynamic, you could just do

`dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);`

after, you can access the objects inside like below:

```cs
foreach(dynamic item in result.packs)
{
  string productCodeScheme = item.pack.productCodeScheme.ToString();
}
```

However, i would strongly suggest that you to deserialize your JSON responses into defined objects instead of using `dynamic`. `dynamics` are both insecure and inefficient. You can do someting like example below,

```cs
public class PackDetails
{
    public string productCodeScheme { get; set; }
    public string productCode { get; set; }
    public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    public string batchId { get; set; }
    public string expiryDate { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string operationCode { get; set; }
    public string warning { get; set; }
    public string information { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class Pack
{
    public PackDetails pack { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseObject
{
    public string operationCode { get; set; }
    public List<Pack> packs { get; set; }
}
```

then you can deserialize a `ResponseObject` like below and use it

```cs
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>();
foreach(PackDetails item in responseObject.packs)
{
  string productCodeScheme = item.pack.productCodeScheme;
}
```